# what will be XSD structure for the following xml---

Tags: xsd

the following is my xml file.what will be XSD structure for the following xml?

```
<sell> 
 <product> 
  <description></description> 
  <details> 
   <name></name> 
   <cost></cost>
  </details> 
 </product> 
</sell>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="sell">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="product">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description"/>
              <xs:element name="details">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cost"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Obtained from http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html

Comment: Yes that matches the simple XML sample given, but somehow I suspect that the product node will be a repeating one.   Also the cost is likely to be a numeric value rather than a string.  @tanmay you may want to supply a XML file that actually contains sample data and also has data for any repeating nodes.